# Azure function import module from azure repos

Tags: python, git, azure-functions, azure-repos

Is it possible to import a module into an azure function straight from another git azure repos?

Instead of having the folder structure proposed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure

```
 __app__
 | - my_first_function
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - my_second_function
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - host.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
 tests
```

and using something like

```
from ..shared_code import my_first_helper_function
```

to import a module, I would like to keep all shared_code in a separate git repository and import from there.

Comment: Who said I downvoted. I edited your question as this a python question and not really anything to do with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` supports [installing from version control](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) which you can leverage directly. Note that your build system would require permission to the git repo if its private.